# AS3 filter function not working when there is 1 item in collection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I've got a list of room objects which is bound to an array collection (in the model) called roomsGroup. I have functions which add or delete rooms from the list, by calling the respective services from the server. Everything works fine  -- until there are no rooms, and I am adding the first one in the list. Then, even though it is correctly added (length of room objects returned from server is 1) it doesn't show up in the UI. If I add a second room, then they BOTH show up.

The entire model class (a singleton) is marked as Bindable, so the public roomsGroup variable is also automatically Bindable.

In the result handler of the 'add room' service, I check for the rooms returned by server, and I put them in a local array collection called rooms. Then I set the Bound roomsGroup in the model=rooms:

```
    model.roomsGroup = rooms;
    model.roomsGroup.refresh(); //I tried adding this but it doesn't help.
    model.roomsGroup.filterFunction = null; //Also tried this, but it doesn't help.
```

In the panel, the list component has its source bound to the model.roomsGroup array collection:

```
 <myPanel:RoomsComponent id="roomsList" roomSource="{model.roomsGroup}"
```

One other thing -- in myPanel there's a textbox where a function called searchContact() is called on keyup. One of the things it does is this:

```
 model.roomsGroup.filterFunction = roomFilterFunction;
 model.roomsGroup.refresh();
```

So I call the service, and the first/only created room doesn't show up. But if I type something in the textbox, then it does show up. In other words, the filter function does cause it to show.

Wondering why, if the bindings are set correctly (and they are, since it works in every other situation than when we're going from zero to one items in the list) it wouldn't work. My best guess is that it has something to do with the filter function, but I don't know exactly what.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not add a dummy room to the list that is not visible and doesn't effect anything, I think that should take care of the problem because when you add the first room to the list, the list size will be 2. This doesn't really answer why there's a problem though.

Comment: You might want to show the code of your filterFunction. Or if possible, provide simple, working example. There doesn't seem to be enough info here to explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to move up this line of code `model.roomsGroup.filterFunction = null;` then your problem will solved.

```
model.roomsGroup = rooms;
model.roomsGroup.refresh(); //I tried adding this but it doesn't help.
model.roomsGroup.filterFunction = null; //Also tried this, but it doesn't help.
```

Block of code changed to

```
model.roomsGroup = rooms;
model.roomsGroup.filterFunction = null; //This should be first line.
model.roomsGroup.refresh(); //This should be second line.
```

Comment: thanks -- tried that but it didn't work. I'm going to try removing the filter function altogether, or else trying to force it to fire.